# How can i read sql query from a .sql file and send that query to connecet my db and get the data

Tags: apache-nifi

I have file in my C drive as like below
sample.sql and that file has sql query inside that like below

### sample.sql(this is my file name)

SELECT * FROM DUAL;

Could any one please help me how can i read that file and data inside the file and connect with my oracle database and execute that query and bring the data back to the processor using apache nifi, appreciate for any configurations with the needed processors, thanks in advance

tried with ListFile processors,FetchFileProcessor,ExtractText processor and ExecuteSQLQureyRecord processor but i am getting as invalid query

Comment: if `;` is part of your file - you have to remove it